# mongoose enforce unique attribute on subdocument property

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I can't tell why unique attribute is not validated in these case

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String},
  email: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
});

var CustomerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
   users:[UserSchema],
});
```

When i push a new user into customer users array i can add the same user with the same email property without raising the duplicate error i would expect.

required attribute rise the an error if property vale is not provided but unique does not

Is this the expected behavior?

for example:

```
var customer = new Customer();
customer.name = 'customer_name';
customer.save(...);

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   var user = new User();
   user.email = 'mg@google.com';
   customer.users.push(user);
   customer.save(...);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/index-unique/) explains:

> The unique constraint applies to separate documents in the collection. That is, the unique index prevents *separate* documents from having the same value for the indexed key, but the index does not prevent a document from having multiple elements or embedded documents in an indexed array from having the same value.

Since you're dealing with embedded documents, you can't enforce uniqueness on a property within the array of embedded documents of the same parent document.

However, when you subsequently try to insert a new `Customer` with a user that also has `mg@google.com` as e-mail address, you will get an error (but only while saving, not when using `.push()`, because uniqueness is enforced by MongoDB, not Mongoose).